# Which OS can I install on my old Synology DS107?

Tags: synology

I have an old Synology DS107 (whose CPU is a Freescale PowerQUICC II MPC8241 PPC SATA, 64-bit) that I would like to recycle.

I cannot find a list of the OS I can install on it. I would like to have a NAS specific OS, but cannot find which I can install.

Any help appreciated ;-)

**Edit**

The main target of this NAS is to become an external save support: I will have one NAS at home and this (DS107)   at a remote place. But the goal is also to be some kind of playground to discover a NAS specific distribution, so as to maybe build my next NAS.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that this kind of question is likely to attract opinion-based answers. Please edit your question to add more details on what specific tasks the OS has to be ready to perform and if there are any other boundary conditions that might help limit the range of possible answers.

Comment: @AdminBee I just updated the description. Thx

Answer (score 2):

[NetBSD wiki indicate it supports it](https://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/sandpoint/instsynology/)

Procedure seems standard & quite accessible with very low electronics (rs232/icl232 chip & few wires) or using a build-in serial cable. Then you can install NetBSD.
It is not NAS-Specific but works well for all type of disk / network management so you will find all you need to manage a NAS.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an old Synology DS107...
>    I would like to have a NAS specific OS...

Synology uses their *Disk Station Manager* (DSM) as the operating system.

this link should download `DSM_DS107_1639.pat` for your specific Synology DS107:

https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download/DS107#firmware

To install the DSM operating system, you need the `Synology Assistant` which can be gotten from here:

https://www.synology.com/en-global/support/download/DS107#utilities

Easiest way:

- need a spare windows computer you can install Synology Assistant on
- once synology assistant installed, run a wired ethernet cable directly from your windows pc to the DS107 NAS (or keep the network as simple as possible),
- power on both, run synology assistant on the windows pc, it should recognize the DS107 on the *network*

  - put new disks in the DS107 and/or push it's reset button first, it will reset out any network config on it and it will try to network via DHCP (which it won't get from your windows computer) and use become some arbitrary 169.254.x.x ip address.   Set you windows pc to a static IP of 169.254.1.1 with netmask of 255.255.0.0 to facilitate this first connection to the DS107 with Synology Assistant.
- synology Assistant will allow you to install the DSM_DS107_1639.pat onto the DS107.

fwiw, synology hardware and probably any NAS for that matter is just a basic computer with a network port and disk controller, probably any linux would *install* onto it and provide some kind of computer functionality, but it would be up to you then to configure everything in linux to make *network attached storage* to happen.  The Synology DSM operating system is fundamentally linux.